# Move a rectangle in sine wave in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am writing a program to move my rectangle on a defined path. I am done with a straight line and a diagonal line, now I want to moe the point in a sine wave, in which we can give frequency and amplitude.

My code for the straight line is

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Generate_clicked()
{


int velocity= MainWindowPtr->ui->horizontalSlider_speed->value();
printf("%d\n",velocity);

QTimer *timer = new QTimer;

// make the connection using the timer variable

connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &generate_video);

// start the timer object by first dereferencing that object first
timer->setInterval(velocity);
timer->start();


}

void generate_video()
{

imageBack= imread(filenameImg);
cvtColor(imageBack, imageBack, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
rectangle(imageBack,Point(initialX,initialY),Point(initialX+widthImg,initialY+heightImg),Scalar(intensity),-1,8,0);
imshow("image",imageBack);

if(MainWindowPtr->ui->radioButton_TrajLine->isChecked())
{
if(initialX>640)
initialX=0;
else
initialX+=1;
}
```

}

Now for sine I am trying something like this:

```
 for (xSin=0;xSin<100;xSin++){
            ySin[(int)floor(xSin)]=10 + 10*sin(2*.1*3.14*xSin);
            rectangle(imageBack,Point(xSin,ySin[xSin]),Point(xSin+widthImg,ySin[xSin]+heightImg),Scalar(intensity),-1,8,0);

        }
```

But nothing is happening. I am using C language in QT on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generate_video function generates one frame each time it is called. If you wish to paste your new code inside it, you should use += as before, instead of for loop, so that only one rectangle it's drawn when called.

```
ySin = 10 + 10*sin(2*.1*3.14*xSin);
xSin += 1
```

Comment: It worked. Also instead of any new variable, I should have used original variables.

`initialY=10 + 10*sin(2*.1*3.14*initialX);`
`initialX += 1;`

Comment: Can you help me out with speed? It's not working properly. When I decrease velocity using slider, it is increasing in output video.
And I can only increase velocity in output, can't reduce it again.

Comment: check when you save a frame to the video, it's most likely because you skip frames when the 'velocity' is higher

Comment: I don't see it anywhere. I am just setting interval after which generate_video() will run. So there isn't any frame to skip before running that function.

Comment: if by output video you mean a video you save (with VideoWriter), its because you see one thing on the screen and save another. Applying pause to the video you see on the screen will not work. You would have to apply different fps to output video, or feed it more frames (slow down the 'animation').